# Swift4 - Is it safe to force unwrap the abbreviation returned using TimeZone.current.abbreviation()?

Tags: swift, timezone, swift4

I was looking for a way to save the local time zone into a property so I can use it to format the date later when I need to display a formatted date later in the UI.

I found `TimeZone.current.abbreviation()` can return the abbreviation for me and I can use that abbreviation to format the date later on, but I've noticed that it returns `String?` instead of `String`.

I've checked the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293351-abbreviation) but found nothing of the reason why that API returns an optional String or what could be the fail case.

My current solution for storing the time zone is `let timeZone = TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!` but I'm not sure if it is safe to force unwrap it. Does anyone know if it is safe to force unwrap the abbreviation returned or why does the API returns an optional value? Thanks.

Comment: I would say it is unsafe unless the documentation says otherwise. – Why don't you store the timezone `identifier` instead?

Comment: @MartinR I've tried using `identifier` but seems like it doesn't indicate whether it is summer time or not as it only returns `Europe/London` to me. If I use abbreviation, I can get `BST` instead.

Comment: No you don't. `TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London").abbreviation()` gives you `GMT+1`.

Comment: @Sweeper But doesn't it the same as `TimeZone.current.abbreviation()`? The `abbreviation()` method returns `String?` instead of `String` is my biggest concern as the fail case isn't documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't documented, I would say there must be a reason that the return value is optional. So it *will* fail sometimes Just check the optional with this:

```
if let abbr = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() {
    // use abbreviation
} else {
    // fall back on something else
}
```

You should be doing this with almost every optional anyway.

I think what's more important here is how you decided to format your date. From your wordings, I suspect that you are not using a `DateFormatter` (or else you won't need to store the abbreviation).

**Use a `DateFormatter`!**

Just store `TimeZone.current` (the whole `TimeZone` object) and assign it to `dateFormatter.timeZone`. The formatter will figure everything out for you. You can use a date format like `yyyy/MM/dd/ HH:mm:ss zzz`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd/ HH:mm:ss zzz"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Shanghai")
formatter.string(from: Date())
```

You seem to also want to show whether it is daylight saving time or not. Use the `isDaylightSavingTime` method of `TimeZone` to check. You can just add a string like `(daylight saving)` at the end.

Comment: I will be using `DateFormatter` but since I'm storing the time zone into the Realm `Object`, I cannot store the whole `TimeZone` object there as it's not supported by Realm. The best solution for me would be store the abbreviation directly so I can show it on the UI later as well.

Comment: Btw if I use identifier to set the time zone for the formatter, how can it tell if it is daylight saving time or not? By the date it receives?

Comment: @WingC. So you are trying to get the time zone from an abbreviation? That seldom works. There are many abbreviation collisions. And as I said, to get whether it is daylight saving time, just call `isDaylightSavingTime()` on the time zone.

Comment: Yes that's my original idea. Didn't think of the abbreviation collision at first tho. Sounds like I must modify my solution. Btw I wasn't mean how can the `identifier` tell me is it daylight saving or not but tell the formatter, coz there'll be an hour difference if it can't tell the formatter if it's summer time or not, but I guess the formatter will judge by the date passes in?

Comment: @WingC. Yeah. Just pass everything to the formatter to handle. The formatter is made specifically for this purpose - so that you worry less about the complexity of date and time.

Comment: @WingC. And if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!